# java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 501 Method Not Implemented in rally

Tags: java, rally

I'm trying to query for a test case from Rally using RallyRestApi. I'm getting a HTTP/1.1 501 Method Not Implemented exception at the QueryResponse. Here's my code:

```
try
    {

        restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com/"), api_key);
        restApi.setProxy(new URI(proxy),userName,pwd);
        restApi.setApplicationName("Rally test results");
        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("Test Case");
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID","=",TCID));
        try{
            QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
            JsonArray result = queryResponse.getResults();
            System.out.println(result);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //System.out.println("NULL response-> restapi");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
```

I wonder what's causing this issue. I have tried a CREATE operation to the same effect. My guess is the proxy server but I have also set the proxy.
Please advice.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the space in the resource name, i.e. "TestCase" instead of "Test Case":

```
    QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
```